# Can the minimum y-value be adjusted when using scales = "free" in ggplot?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Using the following data set:

```
day <- gl(8,1,48,labels=c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Avg"))
day <- factor(day, level=c("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat","Sun","Avg"))
month<-gl(3,8,48,labels=c("Jan","Mar","Apr"))
month<-factor(month,level=c("Jan","Mar","Apr"))

snow<-gl(2,24,48,labels=c("Y","N"))
snow<-factor(snow,levels=c("Y","N"))
count <- c(.94,.95,.96,.98,.93,.94,.99,.9557143,.82,.84,.83,.86,.91,.89,.93,.8685714,1.07,.99,.86,1.03,.81,.92,.88,.9371429,.94,.95,.96,.98,.93,.94,.99,.9557143,.82,.84,.83,.86,.91,.89,.93,.8685714,1.07,.99,.86,1.03,.81,.92,.88,.9371429)
d <- data.frame(day=day,count=count,month=month,snow=snow)
```

I like the y-scale in this graph, but not the bars:

```
ggplot()+
geom_line(data=d[d$day!="Avg",],aes(x=day, y=count, group=month, colour=month))+
geom_bar(data=d[d$day=="Avg",],aes(x=day, y=count, fill=month),position="dodge", group=month)+
scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(d$day))+
facet_wrap(~snow,ncol=1,scales="free")+
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image: geom_bar]

I like the points, but not the scale:

```
ggplot(data=d[d$day=="Avg",],aes(x=day, y=count, fill=month,group=month,label=month),show_guide=F)+
facet_wrap(~snow,ncol=1,scales="free")+
geom_line(data=d[d$day!="Avg",],aes(x=day, y=count, group=month, colour=month), show_guide=F)+
scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(d$day))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
geom_point(aes(colour = month),size = 4,position=position_dodge(width=1.2))
```

[image: geom_point]

1. **How to combine the desirable qualities in the above graphs?**

Essentially, I'm asking: How can I graph the points with a varied y-max while setting the y-min to zero?

*Note: The solution that I'm aiming to find will apply to about 27 graphs built from one dataframe.  So I'll vote up those solutions that avoid alterations to individual graphs.  I'm hoping for a solution that applies to all the facet wrapped graphs.*

*Minor Questions (possibly for a separate post):*
 - *How can I add a legend to each of the facet wrapped graphs?    How
   can I change the title of the legend to read "Weekly Average"?   How
   can the shape/color of the lines/points be varied and then reported
   in one single legend?*

Comment: your other questions would probably be better in their own discussion thread, with a minimal rep example of their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's `expand_limits(y=0)`, which essentially adds a dummy layer with invisible `geom_blank` only to stretch the scales.